# C# XSLT: How to debug this error?

Tags: c#, xslt

I have to include a C# script in my XSLT file .. So as **to calculate the difference between two dateTime values**(and add it to some other values) .. I  **need to accept all the possible formats of date** .. I was suppose to do it with XSLT .. but as XSLT doesn't allow to do it (implicitely) .. I found this remedy of calling a C# script .. I have to call that XSL transformation from many different C# programs .. so It would be painful (rather impossible) to write this code in all calling C# code .. :( Can you find some remedy for this
This is the XSLT code ..

```
 <xsl:variable name="date1" select="//date1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="date2" select="//date2"/>
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="cs">
    <![CDATA[

    private static string[] formats = new string[]
    {
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
        "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
        "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss",
"M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
"M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
"M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
"M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss",
"MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
"MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
"MM/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
"MM/d/yyyy H:mm:ss", 
"M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",   
"M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
"M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", 
"M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss",      
    };


      public string datedif(string date1, string date2) {


            DateTime startTime;
            DateTime endTime;
            DateTime ThirdDate;

string date3="12/12/2009 00:00:00";

            DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out startTime);
            DateTime.TryParseExact(date2, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out endTime);
            DateTime.TryParseExact(date3, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out ThirdDate);

ThirdDate = ThirdDate.Add(endTime.Subtract(startTime));


string result = ThirdDate.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy' 'HH':'mm':'ss");
return(result);

         }
     ]]>
  </msxsl:script>
  <xsl:template match="datediff">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="cs:datedif($date1, $date2)" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

**and the errors are :**

1. The name 'DateTimeStyles' does not exist in the current context
2. The type or namespace name 'CultureInfo' could not be found  (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

ThanQ very much .. Jon Skeet

Comment: apparently the Visual studio debugger supports debugging XSLT (with breakpoints, ...)

Comment: so you want us to debug your code for you?

Comment: I think I'm going to change the menu in my IDE to add please in front of every command - make my PC a much happier place...

Comment: Actually the question is why won't it compile...

Comment: One of the questions is how this is being used - the OP doesn't seem willing to elaborate, instead just saying why each of the answers given isn't useful :(

Comment: Re your comment - actually, xslt *can* be regarded as a programming language (a *functional* programming language). It might not be as simple to write some things, but it is still a programming language.

Comment: ohk .. I have changed ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are errors from the C# compiler. You need to give a lot more information on what you're trying to do.

It sounds like you're *at least* missing a using directive of:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

but you haven't said where the errors are or what you're doing.

EDIT: If you can't change anything else, then change the references to `DateTimeStyles` and `CultureInfo` to be fully qualified:

```
global::System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles
global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo
```

So for example you'd have:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, formats,
     new global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), 
     global::System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out startTime);
```

Comment: I've suggested a workaround in an edit, but you *still* haven't really explained what you're doing.

Comment: They're not statements - my point is that everywhere in the script where you use "DateTimeStyles", use "global::System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles" and the same for CultureInfo.

Comment: And no, you still haven't provided any context. What is this XSLT script being applied to? Why can't you just write a method to do all this in the first place, and call that method?

Answer (score 3):

The bug is on this line:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out startTime);
```

Did you reference the `System.Globalization` namespace?

As @JonSkeet suggested, a workaround is to update your references like so:

```
global::System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles
global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo
```

Comment: @Chris Ballance, I feel sorry for misbehaving .. I am not writing it to convey you to help me in future .. but I just felt like .. that wasn't a proper attitude I could have been thankful for someone who's intended to help .. really sorry ..

Comment: No worries.  The bulk of the folks here are quite nice and very helpful.  Instead of just downvoting answers that aren't 100% correct, ask for clarification or more info and most responders are happy to adjust their answer to better address your question.  I reserve downvotes for clearly wrong answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is often easier to move scripts into extension-objects; you do this by exposing a regular method on a  basic object, and using `XsltArgumentList` to expose it in an xslt namespace:

```
XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
args.AddExtensionObject("my-namespace", obj);
```

In your xslt, you associate your namespace-alias with the namespace, and just use "alias:someFunc(...)" in the xslt. This gives you better IDE support (but you can't just use xslt); example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
public class MyExtensionObject
{
    private static string[] formats = new string[] { /* ... */ };
    public string dateDiff(string x, string y)
    {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        TimeSpan delta = DateTime.ParseExact(y, formats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None)
            - DateTime.ParseExact(x, formats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None);
        return delta.ToString();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
        args.AddExtensionObject("my-namespace", new MyExtensionObject());
        XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();
        xslt.Load("foo.xslt");
        using(TextWriter output = File.CreateText("out.txt")) {
            XPathDocument input = new XPathDocument("foo.xml");
            xslt.Transform(input, args, output);
        }

    }
}
```

xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:bar="my-namespace" >
    <xsl:template match="xml">
      <result value="{bar:dateDiff(date1,date2)}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xml>
  <date1>01/01/2001 00:00:00</date1>
  <date2>2/2/2002 00:00:00</date2>
</xml>
```

Comment: No I can't do it .. I was suppose to do it with XSLT .. but as XSLT is not a programming language .. I found this remedy of calling a C# script .. I have to call that XSL transformation from many different C# programs .. so It would be painful (rather impossible) to write this code in all calling C# code ..  :( Can you find some remedy for this .. thanx for your answer ..

Comment: Then use the explicit approach Jon mentions that doesn't involve any using directives.