# C# XslCompiledTransform using XmlDocument or XPathDocument when editing is required?

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xslcompiledtransform, xpathdocument

I'm going on a couple assumptions here:

1. XPathDocument is not editable.
2. XmlDocument is editable.
3. XPathDocument is more efficient for
   XslCompiledTransform.

That being the case (and please correct me if I am wrong), would it be better (more efficient) to:

1. Make modifications using the
   XmlDocument, then convert to an
   XPathDocument before the transform.
   Is there an optimized way to do
   this?
2. Just stick with the XmlDocument
   through the transform.

Some background, I'm getting a complex xml from a webservice, then use xpath to find some elements which need to be modified, then use a xslt to create html.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Re your comment - there was a near-identical question about that over the weekend. Was that you? If not, I'll try to find it...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888880/c-xslt-how-to-debug-this-error

Comment: Not mine, but I came up with a similar solution, which then had to be thrown away due to the problem I mention below (issue with scripts in the XslCompiledTransform).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how much modification is required, how big the data is, and whether you are familiar with xslt. If "not" to the last, just use `XDocument` etc (last time I ran a profile, `XDocument` was quicker than `XmlDocument` **for my data** - run your own tests). Use `XDocument.Load` / `XDocument.Parse`, find your node, edit it, and save it.

---

If you **must** use xslt, then `XDocument` isn't really an option; once you've loaded it into `XmlDocument` you might as well *stay* with `XmlDocument` - I would not recommend parsing it into a *second* DOM.

Of course, it makes we wonder: why modify the xml *outside* of xslt if you are going to use xslt; perhaps just translate during the xslt?

To get a 100% accurate answer *for your data* you'll need to profile it, of course. But things such as appropriate use of xslt grouping constructs will often make a *much* bigger difference than `XmlDocument` vs `XPathDocument`.

Comment: One reason I need to edit the document is to convert date information (need to convert from filetime to something readable). This cannot be done easily without using script in the xslt, which because of a bug in the XslCompiledTransform is off limits. XslCompiledTransform causes files to be written to windows/temp directory when script is used (without any way of setting a different temp directory). Not good in a farm environment, and systems folks will not allow it.

Anyhow, using xslt to modify the document is not a good solution (there are lots of dates to change and it's alot easier in c#)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `XmlDocument` class for the transform. It would have to be a massive document to really see a performance gain. You may want to compile a static instance of the `XslCompiledTransform` class if you plan on using it multiple times.

Comment: I'm thinking about doing that, I also have already implemented caching of xslt, so I'm not sure how much value using complied versions would add.